# Encoding error in one environment but not in others

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg so apologies for pretending to know what I am talking about here.

I am troubleshooting what should have been a simple ffmpeg install in support of a php website package. Site members can upload videos from their phones to share. Video conversions are failing for some but not all files. So I created a suite of test videos to convert to mp4, using the command line to simplify the environment and get -report output.

This is the command recommended by the php package developers:

./ffmpeg -i {input file} -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 5000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -y {output file}

Four inputs are .mov files, 4 are .mp4 files.

This is the error I get with half of the cases, mostly but not all the larger of the files (50-100MB range):  "Error initializing "output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height Conversion failed!"

I tried to reproduce in two other environments, my Windows 10 desktop and a virtual linux machine using the same distribution as my web host (Fedora 29). But the files all convert without error in those environments.

Using ffmpeg 4.3.1. but see the same results with 4.1.1.

The failure only happens in my shared hosting environment. Can anyone explain what might be happening or, even better, how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Share a report of a failing instance.

Comment: The problem has something to do with multi-threading. FFmpeg chooses optimal threading if none is specified. By using the -thread option to lower the count to 10, all of my test videos were converted as expected, no error failure. But the number 10 was found through trial and error so we don't know how robust it will be in actual usage.
My uneducated guess is that there is some unpredictable interplay between the host being shared with other applications and the availability of threads during the conversion process.